# Как оптимально преобразовать двумерный массив?

Tags: php

Есть массив вида:

```
srcArray = [
    ['name1' => 'value1'],
    ['name2' => 'value2'],
    ['name3' => 'value3'],
];
```

Необходимо привести его к виду:

```
$outArray = ['name1' => 'value1', 'name2' => 'value2', 'name3' => 'value3',]
```

Как можно это оптимально сделать? Такой вариант не выглядит оптимальным:

```
foreach ($srcArray as $arr) {
    $arrayNames[] = array_keys($arr)[0];
    $arrayValues[] = array_values($arr)[0];
}

$outArray = array_combine($arrayValues, $arrayNames);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модификация ответа @DiD с помощью оператора `...`:

```
$srcArray = [
    ['name1' => 'value1'],
    ['name2' => 'value2'],
    ['name3' => 'value3'],
];

print_r(array_merge(...$srcArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$srcArray = [
    ['name1' => 'value1'],
    ['name2' => 'value2'],
    ['name3' => 'value3'],
];
    
$outArray =  array_reduce($srcArray, 'array_merge', []);

var_export($outArray);

?>
```